# how to show this linq query in a label or textbox using c#?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

```
        var priv = from emp in re.Users
                   where emp.Name == struname
                   select new { emp.privilege };
```

for the privilege i have manager, officer and applicant
when i press a button on the form i want to show the (priv) in a label or a textbox i have tried it does not work even when i convert it to string like label.Text= priv.ToString() but it still does not show me mananger, officer or applicant i dont know why 
can you help me please
thanks in advance

Comment: what's priv value after query execution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@r.hamd I saw your auto-answer and I think that, although it works, is very confusing: as Binkan said you are creating and object while you need only a property.

I suggest this cleaner version:

```
Label.Text = re.Users.Single(u=> u.Name == struname).privilege;
```

Of course you have to try-catch this because if match fails you can't access privilege property.

One final note: properties should start with capital letter, therefore you should rename privilege to Privilege.

Comment: for both your suggestion and note i would like to give you my special appreciation brother

Comment: do you have any blog so i can ask you questions while i get? here if i ask a repeated question i get stopped

Comment: no sorry I'm too lazy to have a blog hahaha :) sorry bro

Answer (score 1):

thank you all very much for your contribution

i modified the code as the following and it worked properly for me

```
       var priv = (from emp in re.Users
                   where emp.Name == struname
                   select emp.privilege );
        Label.Text = priv.FirstOrDefault().ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are returning an anonymous type with `select new { emp.privilege }`. Maybe you meant `select emp` or `select emp.privilege`?